# Age's extension using distributed graph processing

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

Since distributed graph processing involves the analyzing large scale graphs distributed across multiple machines. In this approach the large graph data is partitioned into small graphs and all those small graphs are processed on different machines.

My question is that how does Apache Age ensure consistency and reliability in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

As Apache age  ( a graph extension of PostgreSQL)  means that  it inherits the  PostgreSql features  for the data consistency and reliability.

It adds additional mechanisms  to ensure the consistency  and the reliability in graph processing.

It provides us Fault tolerant by allowing multiple replicas of same data  that stored on different machines.

It provides us Distributed   lock manager and master-slave node architecture.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods that can be used to ensure reliability and consistency, some of them are as follows:

1. Replication
2. Fault Tolerance
3. Consistency

The first mechanism helps to make sure that data is always present even if your machine fails.

The second method gives functionality that helps the system to continue working on the alternate machines, if the concerned machine fails.

For the consistency, AGE make sure that every transaction is committed rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

Apache AGE uses various distributed systems concepts such as

- Consistent hashing: This partitions the graph data across multiple machines, which ensures that if a machine fails or joins the cluster, only a small portion of the graph needs to be re-partitioned.
- Replication

Distributed transactions: This ensures that multiple machines can work together to perform a transaction that involves multiple subgraphs. Distributed transactions ensure that all operations in a transaction are either committed or aborted together, ensuring consistency.